# Randomize for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for loop that generates html. I'd for this method to generate the elements randomly. Right now they are cardinally generated i.e. d1, d2, ... di. I want them to follow a random sequence i.e.
d1, di, di-3, .. di-k.

```
         for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n'
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id="row';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='">\n';
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\"t';
          html += id;
          html +='" class=\"ltarget\">'
          html +='</div>\n' 
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n'
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\"d'
          html += id
          html += '\">\n'
          html +=`\t\t\t\t\t\t\t${dlArray[i-numberOfInputs]}\n`;
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n' 
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n';
        }
```

What can I try to accomplish this?

Comment: Google how to create and shuffle an array of ints, then use `arr[i]` instead of `i`. (also there's no need to insert linebreak and tab characters in your HTML, you can use single quotes for inner quotes, and HTML string composition is bad practice in general. You also have a type I guess since you aren't opening the rows with a `<tr>`)

Comment: Would an array of objects also work? And then use the object keys as your values for id, #ofinputs, so on.

Comment: Can you tell us what the end goal is here? As in, add an example table to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly shorter implementation of the table generator using a Durstenfeld shuffle to generate an arbitrary order of the `idx` array which is then used to output the elements of the `dlArray` array:

```js
function shfl(a){
 for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
  if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}

const dlArray="abcdefghij".split(""),
      idx=[...Array(dlArray.length)].map((_,i)=>i+1);
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = '<table id="tablestyle">'
 +shfl(idx).map(i=>
   `<td id="row${i}"><div id="t${i}" class="ltarget">${i}</div></td ><td  id="d${i}">${dlArray[i-1]}</td ></tr>`).join("\n")+'</table>';
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I omitted the `\t` and `\n` characters in my solution as they will not make any difference once the HTML is parsed.